# Utilizar o mesmo Schema dentro de uma chave filha com o Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Estou trabalhando com NodeJS, MongoDB e Mongoose onde estou criando um sistema de permissões de acesso que trabalham com subníveis infinitos. As permissões tem o mesmo Schema:

```
//app/models/PermissaoModel.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PermissaoSchema = new Schema({
  alias: { type: String, unique: true },
  nome: { type: String, required: true },
  descricao: { type: String, default: '' },
  padrao: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  itens: [PermissaoSchema] // <- aqui está meu problema...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Permissao', PermissaoSchema);

//o resultado seria algo como:
permissao:{
  alias,
  nome,
  descricao,
  padrao,
  itens:[permissao, permissao, permissao, permissao, ...]
}
```

Mas ao tentar criar essa estrutura de subníveis, meu código está trazendo um erro dizendo que não posso usá-lo como referência...

Como posso criar uma estrutura de subníveis infinitos para trabalhar com estas permissões?